# c++ Copy file \ Generic implementation

Tags: c++, http, download, copy

I'm looking for a good C++ copy function that encapsulate inside local copy, UNC copy, and HTTP download copy.
something like

bool copy(string path1, string path2) {}

I'm not strong at c++ and have tendency to create memory leaks more than are needed. Is there a complete implementation out there?

Thanks!

Comment: You should try to get strong at C++ then and the tendency to create memory leaks will go away :)

Comment: _more memory leaks then needed_ ? rara are the cases a memory leak is needed ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are asking someone to implement a generic copy function that is able to take various different URI's?

For example, if you want to do HTTP downloads you will need a library that knows HTTP, such as cURL.

The other two, (local path and UNC) should work on Windows, look at using `fstream`. There are plenty of examples.

As it stands this question is extremely vague and isn't really requesting help; merely asking us to implement what sounds like homework.

Comment: No Homework is needed - just wanted to verify if someone already implemented open infrastructure for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Answer (score 0):

The copying is easy:

```
destination << source.rdbuf();
```

Writing the `streambuf` to handles the different sources and
destinations is less obvious, although if you have a good library which
handles all of the dirty work, it shouldn't be too hard to wrap it in a
`streambuf`.  (Otherwise: a robust implementation of any socket protocol
is not something for someone not strong at C++.)